# Using the returned select rows while updating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to update the selected rows based on condition.
The following query returns few rows:

```
select
        b.CRDATTIM,
        b.RECORDCD,
        b.CRNODE,
        b.UNITCD,
        b.WRKTYPE


    from W67U999S a
    join W03U999S b
        on a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE
    where a.PCRDATTIM = '2017-07-20-04.22.20.893340'
    and a.PRECORDCD = 'F'
    and a.PCRNODE = '01'
    and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER'
    and b.UNITCD='CS2XAA';
```

Now I have to update the column `pcrdattim` of `W67u999s`  table which is already used in the above `select` query based on the following `where` condition

```
W67u999s.ccrdattim=returned select row.crdattim
```

I have tried with the following query, but it's not working.:

```
update W67u999s set pcrdattim='2017-07-31-07.40.42.355440' from W67U999S as a inner join W03U999S as b on a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE
    where a.PCRDATTIM = '2017-07-20-04.22.20.893340'
    and a.PRECORDCD = 'F'
    and a.PCRNODE = '01'
    and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER'
    and b.UNITCD='CS2XAA'
    and a.ccrdattim=crdattim and b.crecordcd='T';
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you create a view on the select statement and use it in the update? or just use : update table from (inner SQL)  set <condition>  followed by join condition.

Comment: I thing view will further complicate the query. Can't we do without using any view? I mean just by using `joins`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query worked for me(`exists` did the magic here):

```
update W67U999S a set pcrdattim= '2017-07-31-07.40.42.355440'
where exists 
(select
        b.CRDATTIM,
        b.RECORDCD,
        b.CRNODE,
        b.UNITCD,
        b.WRKTYPE
    from W03U999S b

    where a.PCRDATTIM = '2017-07-20-04.22.20.893340'
  and  a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM 
  and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD 
  and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE
    and a.PRECORDCD = 'F'
    and a.PCRNODE = '01'
    and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER'
    and b.UNITCD='CS2XAA' and a.crecordcd='T');
```

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` is your friend in this case. A `MERGE` allows you to just use a `JOIN` (like you already have) and use it as a base for an `UPDATE` on the table.

The `MERGE` needs a connection from the `USING` clause to the table to be updated. In most use cases, using the primary key is fine for that. As you did not provide full table structure, see this example and adapt it to your needs.

```
merge into W67U999S t 
using (

    select
        a.primary_key, b.CRDATTIM -- change this line

        /*
            b.CRDATTIM,
            b.RECORDCD,
            b.CRNODE,
            b.UNITCD,
            b.WRKTYPE
        */

        from W67U999S a
        join W03U999S b
            on a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE
        where a.PCRDATTIM = '2017-07-20-04.22.20.893340'
        and a.PRECORDCD = 'F'
        and a.PCRNODE = '01'
        and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER'
        and b.UNITCD='CS2XAA'
) u
on (t.primary_key = u.primary_key)
when matched then update set t.pcrdattim = u.CRDATTIM
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help :

```
update W67U999S from 
(
    select
            b.CRDATTIM,
            b.RECORDCD,
            b.CRNODE,
            b.UNITCD,
            b.WRKTYPE


        from W67U999S a
        join W03U999S b
            on a.CCRDATTIM = b.CRDATTIM and a.CRECORDCD = b.RECORDCD and a.CCRNODE = b.CRNODE
        where a.PCRDATTIM = '2017-07-20-04.22.20.893340'
        and a.PRECORDCD = 'F'
        and a.PCRNODE = '01'
        and b.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER'
        and b.UNITCD='CS2XAA'
) X
set  W67u999s.ccrdattim= X.crdattim
where
    W67U999S.CCRDATTIM = X.CRDATTIM 
    and W67U999S.CRECORDCD = X.RECORDCD 
    and W67U999S.CCRNODE = X.CRNODE
```

Comment: Oracle does not support this syntax. You could probably achieve something similar using `MERGE` though.